# JQuery Fancybox - How to reload page when fancybox closes

Tags: jquery, fancybox, reload

How can I reload the current page when a user closes a Fancybox dialogue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fancybox` `onClosed` handler for that;

```
$('#some_element').fancybox({
  onClosed: function() {
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: `onClosed` is no longer the correct callback. The correct one (as of Fancybox v2) is `afterClose`

Answer (score 0):

Please use "afterClose" handler. 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/2802/)

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox(
{ 
    afterClose: function() 
    {
     window.location.reload();
    }
});
```